# Boostrap: Why does input group button revert to default grey when mouse away?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a visualization of my problem:
[image]

I tried to change the default grey background color by using CSS. Somehow the default grey background seems to stick even though I changed the background color of the `Add-Button` and `Remove-Button`. I would really appreciated some help on this!

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" id="Remove-Button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Remove">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
              <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" id="Add-Button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Add">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS color buttons part**

```
/*Color button & icons*/

#Add-Button:hover {
  background-color: #E5FFFB;
}

#Remove-Button:hover {
  background-color: #FCC1C5;
}
```

[JSFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/k1pjs79c/)

Comment: you did not change the background color of the :focus state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I fixed my own problem by doing

```
#Add-Button, #Remove-Button {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have the code `#Add-Button:hover, #Add-Button:focus { background: ... }`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `#AddButton:focus` which bootstrap has a default gray value for. If you want to remove it or change it you need to add that into your css. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/0w1u0dcr/1/

EDIT: I just reread your question, and realized that you wanted it for both buttons. If you wanted to target both of them in the same css line, this is another option http://jsfiddle.net/x7p4s9ug/

Comment: hmm but with your 2nd solution the background color no longer reappears after you click on the button and then re-hover over it

Comment: Oh whoops, you're right. It's because I added the `!important` to the background under the :focus, and it overrides the :hover one. You could fix that by adding `!important` to the hover values like so http://jsfiddle.net/Lwvf23t4/1/ , but I feel like just writing another id for your other button is simpler at that point lol